# SQL Query for a one to many relationship

Tags: php, select, one-to-many

I have two tables, Table A and Table B. For each record in table A there are many records in Table B; thus, a one to many relationship exists between tables A and B. I want to perform a query so that for each row returned from table A, all of the corresponding rows will be returned from table B. From what I understand I'll need to use a `INNER Join` - however, how would I go about accessing all of the returned rows through say, PHP?

```
$sql = "Select A.ID, B.Name * From A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID";
```

```
A.ID  |  B.fName        |  B.lName
1          nameone         lnameone
1          nametwo         lnametwo
2          namethree       lnamethree
4          namefour        lnamefour
```

Now that I have the above results, I want to use PHP to loop through all of the values of `B.Name` only for a single `A.ID` at a time. So, the results I want would look like:

```
1.
nameOne lNameOne
nameTwo lnametwo

2. namethree lNamethree

4. nameFour lNameFour
```

Basically, I'm trying to group the query results by the ID in table A.

I appreciate the help very much!

Thank you,

Evan

Comment: What database system are you using? Can you perform a simple select and iterate over the returned result set?  If you can, you can do what you want in exactly the same manner.  There is no difference in what you do with the PHP just because the SQL contains a JOIN clause

Comment: MYSQL, and I can easily loop through using mysql_fetch_assoc, but I want to do a loop within a loop, basically and base the loop on A.ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just Google "php get from database," and use some normal array pre-processing, but I worry the advice you find may not be ideal.  Here's what I'd do:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=dbname', 'user', 'pass');
$result = $pdo->query(<<<SQL
   SELECT
      ID,
      Name
   FROM
      A
      -- Alternative to `JOIN B USING(ID)` or `JOIN B ON (A.ID = B.ID)
      NATURAL JOIN B
SQL
);
$a = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
   if (!isset($a[$row['ID']]) {
      $a[$row['ID']] = array();
   }
   $a[$row['ID']][] = $row['Name'];
}
```

You could also `GROUP BY` the `ID` and `GROUP_CONCAT` the names to be `explode`d in PHP later to skip the manual array creation and reduce some iteration (although SQL will do more in that case).

Comment: woah, that's a whole lot of information. Alright, so I'm assuming that "fetch" is unique to PDO - could I do this same thing using $row = mysql_fetch_assoc) ?

Comment: @Evan this is my way of strongly suggesting that you use PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a simple `ORDER BY A.ID` to the SQL query would probably get you quite far in "grouping" the items together. It's difficult to give a more detailed answer without knowing exactly what you want to do with the "groups".